# R: rolling standard deviation with startpoint at the first index and ignore NA

Tags: r, statistics, standard-deviation

How do I compute the rolling standard deviation of a vector, such that

1. it ignores NA
2. always computing the rolling standard deviation **from the first index**
3. returns a rolling standard deviation vector with length same as the input vector

?

Example:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- c(NA, rnorm(5), NA, rnorm(5))
```

The result will return

```
sd(x[1:1],na.rm=T) = NA
sd(x[1:2],na.rm=T) = NA
sd(x[1:3],na.rm=T) = 0.2335561
sd(x[1:4],na.rm=T) = 1.140186
sd(x[1:5],na.rm=T) = 0.9355676
sd(x[1:6],na.rm=T) = 0.8110218
sd(x[1:7],na.rm=T) = 0.8110218
sd(x[1:8],na.rm=T) = 0.9550024
sd(x[1:9],na.rm=T) = 0.8718094
sd(x[1:10],na.rm=T) = 1.009344
sd(x[1:11],na.rm=T) = 0.9928846
sd(x[1:12],na.rm=T) = 0.9537841
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rollapplyr` from `zoo`.

```
zoo::rollapplyr(x, seq_along(x), sd, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]   NA    NA 0.234 1.140 0.936 0.811 0.811 0.955 0.872 1.009 0.993 0.954
```

---

Or a manual way in base R which would be slow than the `zoo` approach.

```
sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sd(x[1:i], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: what is window_size ?

Comment: As specified in the question,  I want to do roll calculations always starting from the first index.

Comment: Thank you for adding an example. I have updated the answer.

Comment: A second rollapplyr solution would be `rollapplyr(x, length(x), sd, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE)`